# How to stop Prettier from tabbing every list item after the first one in Visual Studio Code? (Markdown)

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, prettier

## Problem (Markdown)

##### When I have **any** kind of list, every list item after the first is being tabbed for no reason.

> Currently on save

```
- [Dashboard](#dashboard)
  - [Table of Contents](#table-of-contents)
  - [Running as a developer](#running-as-a-developer)
  - [Data Tab](#data-tab)
  - [Disclaimer](#disclaimer)
```

> Desired result on save

```
- [Dashboard](#dashboard)
- [Table of Contents](#table-of-contents)
- [Running as a developer](#running-as-a-developer)
- [Data Tab](#data-tab)
- [Disclaimer](#disclaimer)
```

How can I fix this within VS Code?

### Tried:

- Change Prettier tab width
- Format document with another formatter like "Markdown All in one"

> Prettier Configuration

VS Code Extension: Prettier - Code formatter(esbenp.prettier-vscode)

Comment: Do you have [a Prettier configuration](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html)? If so, you need to provide a [mre] including the Prettier configuration file of that [mre] (emphasis on "minimal" and "example").

Comment: I don't have a prettier configuration : ) at all 

What would you advice to be inside of the config to fix this?

Comment: what prettier version are you on, and how are you using it? Are you using it via commandline? Or through an extension? If via extension, also include what the ID of the extension is, ideally with a link to its Visual Studio Marketplace page and what version of it you are using.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am using Prettier via VS Code extension. Here is the extension ID: esbenp.prettier-vscode

Comment: I can't reproduce this on VS Code 1.75 on Windows with `esbenp.prettier-vscode` version  9.10.4. Can you open the output log channel for the prettier extension (View > Output > Prettier) and show us the text of what you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. There is nothing wrong with prettier.

The issue was that in my markdown file this is how my headers were :

```
    # Dashboard
    ## ...
    ## ...
```

For the table of contents ... major sections must have the **same** amount of '#'. That's why prettier kept tabbing the rest. (more hashtags mean subsections)

So originally, I set it up such that everything is a subsection of "Dashboard".

Fix:

```
    ## Dashboard
    ## ...
    ## ...
```